# Can't make the required diagram

Tags: vhdl, diagram

This is the code for a 9-bit parity generator, but it is not giving the required RTL view in Quartus

```
Library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity PG is
port (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I : IN std_logic;
      Even : OUT std_logic );
end PG;

Architecture arch of PG is
    Signal J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Odd : std_logic ;
BEGIN
    J <= A xor B;
    K <= C xor D;
    L <= E xor F;
    M <= G xor H;
    N <= J xor K;
    O <= L xor M;
    P <= N xor O;
    Odd <= P xor I;
    Even <= not Odd;
END arch;
```

This is the required image that is required as output:

[image: required]

This is the output RTL image that I get:

[image: actual]

Comment: Please consider rephrasing your question, marking the exact issue, and showing some signs of personal effort. Otherwise it could be downvoted. Your code seems fine however.

Comment: What is the desired diagram? What diagram do you get instead?

Comment: I have put the images !!

Comment: So I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the correct RTL view to me. Quartus has chosen to display the logic as one 9-input XOR gate instead of many 2-input XOR gates. The boolean behaviour of both is identical. There is no ODD output, because ODD is a `signal` not an output.

Comment: Matthew Taylor, Thankyou

Comment: XOR is associative as well as commutative.